# Use docker-compose service names in Nginx config

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an application with 4 services. One of them is Nginx which will act as a proxy. 
I use docker compose to run the services. In nginx when I specify a path and where to proxy I want to be able to use the service name. This is what I have done so far.

```
version: '3'
services:
  go_app:
    image: go_app
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"

  mysql:
    image: mysql_db
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"

  flask_app:
    image: flask_app
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"

  nginx:
    image: nginx_app
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
      - flask_app
      - go_app
```

With the above I create all services. They all work on their respective ports. I want Nginx to listen on port 80 and proxy as defined in the config:

```
server {
listen 0.0.0.0:80;
server_name localhost;

location / {
  proxy_pass http://${FLASK_APP}:8080/;
  }
}
```

You may ask where does FLASK_APP come from. I specify it inside nginx docker image:

```
FROM nginx

ENV FLASK_APP=flask_app
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY config/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Nginx container keeps failing with the following error:

```
[emerg] 1#1: unknown "flask_app" variable
nginx: [emerg] unknown "flask_app" variable
```

The way I understand docker compose, `flask_app` should resolve as the flask_app service.
What am I doing wrong/misunderstanding?

Comment: can you share your docker-compose command? can you try to remove `ENV FLASK_APP=flask_app` from Dockerfile and check if `ping flask_app` succeeds from nginx?

Comment: `docker-compose up -d` is the command I run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that nginx does not read ENV  variables .

see  https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/nginx#using-environment-variables-in-nginx-configuration

a solution :
  you can modify you dockerfile for `nginx` with this

```
FROM nginx
ENV FLASK_APP=flask_app
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/bin/bash","-c","envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

the `COPY` command is modified to copy you configuration as a template.

the last line is modified to do a substitution using your ENV variables.

Comment: The reason I did it the way i did is because I saw something similar here: https://github.com/instana/robot-shop/blob/master/web/default.conf.template. If you look at individual docker files they also define variables there, I thought that's the way to do this.

Comment: Oh, I noticed now that they run a script before nginx runs and they also use `envsubst`. I will try this later